# Passing a struct from c++ to c# when the structure is only known during runtime

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

I have the following problem:

I have a C# app that calls functions from an unmanaged C++ dll. There's an initialization function in the dll which creates an interface between the C# and C++ (basically a list of values and their types) that will be stored in a struct.

After that, there's a callback function that the C# app sends to the dll, which the dll calls every once in a while, and it returns a struct variable (or a bytes array) as it was defined in the interface.

My question: How would you pass and marshal this struct? is it possible to pass the struct itself, or should I pass a byte array?

If you pass a byte array, how would you marshal it when returned to the C# app?

What I have right now:

In the C# app:

Marshaling the callback function:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void ProcessOutputDelegate(???); // not sure what should be here.
```

Importing the dll function:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Test(ProcessOutputDelegate ProcessOutput);
```

Calling the dll function:

```
ProcessOutputDelegate process = new ProcessOutputDelegate(ProcessOutput);
new thread(delegate() { Test(process); } ).Start();
```

Processing the output:

```
public void ProcessOutput(???)
{
    // Assume we have a list of values that describes the struct/bytes array.
}
```

In the C++ dll I have the following struct (this is an example, as a different dll may be called in different runtimes):

```
struct
{
    int x;
    double y;
    double z;
} typedef Interface;
```

And the function called by the C# app:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Test(void (*ProcessOutput)(Interface* output))
{
    int i;
    Interface* output = (Interface*)malloc(sizeof(Interface));

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        sleep(100);
        output->x = i;
        output->y = i / 2;
        output->z = i / 3;
        ProcessOutput(output); // or generate a bytes array out of the struct
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The C# application is a generic GUI, that suppose to show some heavy computations  performed by some c++ dll. In the initialization process, the dll tells the GUI about the variables (and their types) that should be presented and the GUI is constructed according to these directions (again, the computation and variables may change, and the values may be ints, floats, chars...). After that, the dll runs and in each couple of time steps, it calls the callback function to update the GUI. This should work with any dll that implements this idea: generating an interface, then sending information according to this interface.

Comment: I don't understand the part where the C++ struct "may vary". In plain C++, structs are defined at compile time. They don't magically change during runtime (their contents certainly, but not their structure). Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Mat True, the meaning is that a different dll may be called in each runtime, i'll add a clarification. each dll will implement the function "Test" but may construct a different struct and perform different actions.

Comment: So you're trying to use the same C# interface for different C++ DLLs that may "return" completely different things? I'm sorry your whole thing sounds really strange. Without concrete examples of what you're applying this to, it's going to be hard (I think) to provide good advice. Possibly interface with XML or JSON if it's completely random stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with this setup you could just use a byte pointer or something, but the size of the struct you're passing is still unknown, you somehow need to pass `sizeof(Interface)`.

Comment: Again, please clarify what you want to do with the data that is passed to your function.

Comment: @Mat I'll try to better explain myself- the C# app doesn't (and shouldn't) know what the dll is processing, it only knows a function with a specific name exists in this dll and that a vector of values will be return, information about this vector will be passed from the dll to the C# app in some initialization process, is that any clearer?

Comment: A vector of values (something like `std::vector<int>`) is not a variable structure. And if the C# code doesn't know what it'll get, what's it going to do with whatever it receives?

Comment: @Mat I've added some explanation about what i'm doing. I'm generating the GUI according to this interface, and updating the GUI according to the data passed each time.

Comment: You are not thinking about this problem clearly yet.  Maybe you are used to C#'s PropertyGrid control, it can magically show any property of an arbitrary object.  This however requires lots of plumbing, it uses Reflection support built in .NET.  That just doesn't exist in C++, passing a raw pointer to the native object leaves C# entirely incapable of guessing what that pointer points to.

Comment: @HansPassant Can't I put the information as a bytes array, give the c# a pointer to it and the size of it, then marshal it (according to the declared interface)?

Comment: Well, sure.  As long as C# only ever needs to interpret them as just raw bytes.  That is liable to produce a less than useful user interface, something like a hex dump.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, whether this is a direct answer to your problem, but I solved it in the following way.

1. You call GetResource in the DLL and get an IntPtr:

   ```
   (...)
   IntPtr res = Native.GetResource();
   ```
2. Then, you instantiate a generic wrapper for this IntPtr:

   ```
   ResourceWrapper rw = new ResourceWrapper(res);
   ```
3. If you want to access specific fields of the structure, you call appropriate methods on the wrapper:

   ```
   int field = rw.GetField();
   ```
4. Wrapper calls a function in the DLL:

   ```
   (...)
   int result = Native.GetField(res);
   ```
5. DLL "re-objectizes" the call:

   ```
   __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall GetField(MyStructure * s)
   {
       return s->GetField();
   }
   ```
6. Struct gets the data (or throws an exception or sets error flag or returns error etc.)

   ```
   int MyStructure::GetField()
   {
       return this->field;
   }
   ```

This solution requires the following changes:

- Your data structures should derive from the same base class
- If it is possible, they should become classes with virtual methods allowing access to their different fields
- You have to implement some kind of security mechanism, which checks, whether access to specific field is possible or not. The simplest one is the following:

  ```
  __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall GetField(MyStruct * s, int & result)
  {
      result = 0;
      try
      {
          result = s->GetField();
      }
      catch(...)
      {
          return FALSE;
      }

      return TRUE;
  }
  ```

  and:

  ```
  protected class Native
  {
      [DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool GetField(IntPtr res, out int result);
  }
  ```

  and:

  ```
  // Wrapper
  int GetField()
  {
      int result;
      if !(Native.GetField(res, out result))
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Resource does not support field!");
  }
  ```